# ScalaMock Inheritied Trait Function of Object ScalaTest

Tags: scala, unit-testing, architecture, scalatest, scalamock

I am attempting to test a function, however the function that I am testing makes a call to the traits function which I would like to stub. I can't seem to stub this function using ScalaMock, as I am unable to mock the object.

```
trait[A<:CommonReturn] commonTrait[A] {
    def commonFunction(s:String):(String,String) = {
        ("Hello","World")
    }
    def testMe(s:String) : A
}
```

This trait is then extended by many Objects each implementing commonTrait and returning their specific sub-type of common return.

```
object ob extends commonTrait[ConcreteType] {
    override def testMe(s:String){
        val(x,y) = commonFunction(s)
        val z = "unique logic"
        ConcreteType(x,y,z)
    }
}
```

I therefore am now trying to test ob.testMe however I can't seem to Mock the ob Object, therefore can't stub the commonFunction.

Is this due to my architecture? Or is it possible to mock an object with scalamock and use scalatest?

```
val mocked = mock[ob]
(mocked.commonFunction _).expect(*).returning("test","test")
```

This doesn't compile.

Comment: would you have the same problem if commonFunction was outside of testMe in your example?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mock objects with ScalaMock, as a mock[X] is a subclass of X. Scala does not allow subclasses of objects.

If you need to test collaboration with this `commonFunction` then inheritance makes it rather difficult. I would consider designing this with Dependency Injection instead.